# Puma does not seem to be opening the port it says it is

Tags: port, puma

I'm developing a Rails app using Puma as the server on my local machine.

When I start the local server, the logs clearly indicate that Puma is opening a connection on `localhost:3011`:

```
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 5.0.4 application starting in development on http://localhost:3011
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
Puma starting in single mode...
* Version 3.9.1 (ruby 2.3.4-p301), codename: Private Caller
* Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
* Environment: development
* Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:3000
Use Ctrl-C to stop
```

But when I run `netstat` to see the open port, port 3011 does not seem to be active:

```
kevin@kevin-devbox:~/Programming$ netstat -an | grep "3011"
(there is no output)
kevin@kevin-devbox:~/Programming$
```

How do I go about figuring out why my local server isn't opening the port it says it is?

Comment: Experimenting some more, I noticed that the server is listening to port 3000. Why is it doing so, and how do I make it listen to port 3011?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statements prefixed with `=>` are coming from Rails, which sometimes doesn't get the right information. [You can see the source for that log statement here.](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/ad3aaadce0f8fb977aa2bd1c551160e83d7dac03/railties/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb#L66)

What really matters for binding ports is puma's bindings, which are revealed lower in the logs. [You can see the source for that log here.](https://github.com/puma/puma/blob/0912b0cea1576e96ee4e84a84cfff2a80750ecf6/lib/puma/binder.rb#L104) You can make these work in a couple different ways:

- Add the `-p` flag to the server command: `rails s -p 3000`
- Add `bind 'tcp://0.0.0.0:3000'` to `config/puma.rb`.